# Windows 10 January Preview Update failure

Tags: windows-10-preview

I have Windows 10 October preview installed. Yesterday I got the January preview update pushed to me. But when I install it, in the last step, I got the error dialog like with message like below

> Windows could not configure one or more system components. To install
>   Windows, restart the computer and then restart the installation.

I thought the problem is that I don't have enough space on C drive, I then deleted a few things from C drive, leave roughly 19G on it, tried to install the update again, still I got the same error. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: If you boot from a boot disc that can navigate and read the Windows file system, navigate to C:\Windows\Panther\setuperr.log , read the error log for more clues as to what went wrong.

Comment: [More details here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825073.aspx)

Comment: No. I am not installing the January preview with a disc or usb. Instead through Preview Updates which is pushed to me directly.

Comment: Does not matter how it was installed, my comment is on how to diagnose the problem by reading the setup error logs generated when you attempted to update or install.

Comment: The thing is that the Panther folder is empty

Comment: Then it is some sort of hardware problem, hard to diagnose without logs.